# Trying to initiate a Maps Activity after clicking a item in a Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist

Recently I'm doing an app that have a *Navigation Drawer* and I have some items wich clik it should open a maps activity but when doing so my app stops and show me the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: jocadoci.soloordena, PID: 2897 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 
  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255) 
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308) 
  at jocadoci.soloordena.MapsItaly.geoLocate(MapsItaly.java:99) 
  at jocadoci.soloordena.MapsItaly.onMapReady(MapsItaly.java:73) 
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source) 
  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source) 
  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380) 
  at wl.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82) 
  at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I supposed that the error is because in the maps activity I have the following class that use the ArrayList.java created by android studio.

```
private void geoLocate() throws IOException {
    String location = "comida rapida y pizza";
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>(gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1));
    Address address = list.get(0);
    String locality = address.getLocality();

    Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    double lat = address.getLatitude();
    double lng = address.getLongitude();
    goToLocationZoom(lat, lng, 16);

}
```

But I'm not sure what the error is. I appreciate any help and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Geocoder.getFromLocationName` will return null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int))).

So, to solve your problem you must check if there are available results:

```
private void geoLocate() throws IOException {
    String location = "comida rapida y pizza";
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>(gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1));

    if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
        Address address = list.get(0);
        String locality = address.getLocality();

        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        double lat = address.getLatitude();
        double lng = address.getLongitude();
        goToLocationZoom(lat, lng, 16);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No results found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that help to be able to see my maps activity. You know how do to the string actually show locations like google maps do?